# Angular app only redirects after second click event

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm having an issue where my app will only redirect after the second `on click` event. I've placed console logs all over the code and I can see the the logs I've set up after the `location.path()` call.

On the second `on click` event the app will redirect straight away(before the `searchTeam` function has a chance to complete). Any ideas what I am doing wrong? Below is the code.

```
function SearchController($scope, $location, API, ENV, SignUpShared) {
    var vm = this;
    vm.cdnBaseUrl = ENV.cdnBaseUrl;
    vm.shared = SignUpShared;

    vm.shared.emailConfirmation = undefined;
    vm.submit = function() {

        if($scope.emailAddress && $scope.emailAddress.trim().length > 0) {
            API.searchTeam($scope.emailAddress).then(function() {
                vm.shared.emailType = vm.shared.FIND_TEAM;
                vm.shared.emailConfirmation = $scope.emailAddress;
                $location.path("/emailconfirmation");
            });
        }
    };
}

SearchController.$inject = ["$scope", "$location", "API", "ENV", "SignUpShared"];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Might be the issue with AngularJS event handle timeout. Try below code and hope this will work for you.

```
if($scope.emailAddress && $scope.emailAddress.trim().length > 0) {
    API.searchTeam($scope.emailAddress).then(function() {
        vm.shared.emailType = vm.shared.FIND_TEAM;
        vm.shared.emailConfirmation = $scope.emailAddress;
        $timeout(function () {
            $location.path("/emailconfirmation");
        }, 0);
    });
}
```

Also, update inject array accordingly.

```
SearchController.$inject = ["$scope", "$location", "API", "ENV", "SignUpShared", "$timeout"];
```